# iOS facebook graph request completion handler block not called

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios9

I'm using Facebook iOS SDK and Parse to handle user login through Facebook on one of my apps. However, after building app with iOS 9 SDK, the app seems failed to fetch information from Facebook's graph API.

Here is the code snippets I used to pull information from Facebook

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields":@"name,email,id,gender"} HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"%@",result);
}];
```

After setting a breakpoint, I found the `completionHandler` block was not called at all, meaning there is no results nor error from the call...

I have changed the `info.plist` file based on instructions for [iOS 9 on Facebook website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9). And the app is using Facebook login and it worked completed fine for logging in.

When the user logging in, the permission I used for the app is `@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_friends"]`.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show your code for `logInWithReadPermissions`

Comment: I have the same problem. Let me know if you figure it out

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same problem!

Comment: Did you find the problem with this?

Comment: Anyone figure this out/

Answer (score 0):

It might should be a complete code like below this

```
FBRequest *meRequest=[[FBRequest alloc]initWithSession:self.session graphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me"]parameters:@{@"fields":@"name,email"} HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[meRequest startWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
   NSDictionary* result,
   NSError *error)
 {
     fbCompletion(result,error);
 }];
```